# Code unreachable when comparing types

Tags: c#, if-statement, types, compare, unreachable-code

### **Question: My else-statement is unreachable, what am i doing wrong?**

very VERY new at programming and i'm trying to compare the type so for example people can't enter strings when i'm asking for integers.

My code is probably pretty bad, if i could get a header what to do and why the if-argument skips the else-part i'd be really happy!

Thanks!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        int integer = 0;

        start:
        Console.WriteLine("How old are you?: ");
        int svar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Utility.CompareTypes(svar, integer);

            if (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thanks");

        }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have to enter a number!");
                goto start;
            }

    }
}

class Utility
{

    public static bool CompareTypes<T01, T02>(T01 type01, T02 type02)
    {
        return typeof(T01).Equals (typeof(T02));
    }

}
```

:c

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: please avoid `goto's` in your code very bad coding practice in my opinion

Comment: i(true) is wrong, there is no sense in such a line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really a question of code, but of logic...

```
if (true) // <--- this will ALWAYS be true
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thanks");
}
else // <--- therefore this will NEVER happen
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have to enter a number!");
    goto start;
}
```

Since your `else` block can never possibly execute under any logical circumstance, the entire block of code can be simplified to:

```
Console.WriteLine("Thanks");
```

In order for the `else` block to execute, the condition checked in the `if` statement needs to be `false`.  You're currently not checking any actual condition, just a hard-coded `true` value.

Perhaps you meant to use the result of the previous line of code?  Something like this:

```
var typesAreSame = Utility.CompareTypes(svar, integer);

if (typesAreSame)
{
    //...
```

Comment: Yes! That was i was looking for; thank you David!

Comment: @ArvidWikströmWiren Then you should mark it as the answer.